# JavaFX - What is the correct way to give a Shape subclass object like Rectangle no Color

Tags: javafx, shapes

I found out that a way to do this is to simply just pass `null` to `setFill(Color color)` but that seems like a hacker solution to me. I am wondering if there is a better/proper way to do this?

```
    CubicCurve cubicCurve = new CubicCurve(
            50,
            75,
            80,
            -25,
            110,
            175,
            140,
            75);
    cubicCurve.setStrokeType(StrokeType.CENTERED);
    cubicCurve.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    cubicCurve.setStrokeWidth(3);
    cubicCurve.setFill(null); //this is in my opinion a hacker solution
```

That also brings me to my second question, why is the default fill color white for any shape? Is there an efficiency reason for this? What is the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant way to write it would be to assign the fill as `TRANSPARENT` for a similar effect.

```
cubicCurve.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

As far as your other questions are concerned, the default fill is `Black` and not `White`. I have no idea about the reason behind it. This is how the JavaFX developers decided it to be.

In the [`Shape.java`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/d3e98984c2bb/modules/graphics/src/main/java/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.java#l372) :

```
public final Paint getFill() {
    return fill == null ? Color.BLACK : fill.get();
}
```

Comment: Probably simply because BLACK is 0?

Comment: Yes, i. e. the default fill being black.

Comment: Do you think that is more efficient?